# C - Values under the same array index are different

Tags: c, arrays

I am analyzing a C code that I have been given and I came across this block:

```
for (k=0; k<m; k++)
{
   //Perform some calculation and assign result to 
   //A[k].
   if (A[k]!=A[k])
   {
      exception=1; 
   }
 }
```

I have performed runs of the code where `exception` does turn out to be one, but I can't seem to understand how two array indices can contain different numbers! Is that something to do with machine precision? Thank you!

Comment: Not possible at all..!!

Comment: @janki I said that when I first saw it... but it is a fact!

Comment: There are many questions here... What is the type of `A` array? Are you sure `exception` was not `1` before you entered the loop? Is your program one-thread only? Possibly some other code manipulates your `A[]` data or `exception` value (or even the `k` value!) in the same time? Show a minimal but complete, running example.

Comment: @CiaPan Sure about first point! I use OMP constructs to speed processes up, but `A[k]` is declared as `private`. Thanks!

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @arekolek Unfortunately the code is massive and possibly proprietary. The sample snippet is part of a simulation which traverses a domain and calculates different things. As for the verifiable example - that depends on the initial conditions and there are many of them. Any suggestions of how to go about this?

Comment: You have two options, and probably should try them both: *code is massive and possibly proprietary* -> **Restart from scratch. Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem.** *depends on the initial conditions and there are many of them* -> **Divide and conquer. When the source of the problem is entirely unclear, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back.** Also, if the code is in a git repository, you could use `git bisect`.

Comment: @arekolek Thank you! I will do my best to uncover the reason and I will let you know!

Comment: What type exactly is `A`? Is overloading the `[]` operator involved here? Is your program multithreaded?

Comment: @MichaelWalz `A` is a `float`. I am not entirely sure what operator overloading is. Sorry. Yes, as mentioned above I use OMP to parallelize it. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterHristov overloading is a c++ thing, forget it (at least for this question). But yes OMP might be the cause of the problem here.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Would you care to shed some more light? Maybe not here as it might be seen as spam. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterHristov it's just an idea, the 4 lines of code you have posted in your question are not enough to draw any conclusions.

Comment: The problem was that the value written to `A[k]` was getting very large and going to `NaN` for which the code in the OP is apparently a well-known check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check whether the A[] array is allocated sufficient amount of memory: it should have 'm' elements allocated at least. If everything is OK, check the sizes of other arrays allocated in your program. The phenomenon that you've encountered looks like some memory allocation error.

Comment: The thing is that A is allocated in the very beginning (statically!) with A[m]! I don't understand what the sizes of other arrays might have to do with it?! Thanks

Comment: Statically, with 'm' ? In that case, 'm' must be a constant, not a variable. If it was defined something like #define m 100000  , that would be OK. Regarding the sizes of other arrays: if some other array has less memory allocated than it should have, operations with "non-existent" elements would easily corrupt other parts of the code, and the program may fail in an absolutely unexpected part of the code.

Comment: Apologies for the terminology slip! I meant `int A[8];` if m was to be 8. Thanks for the information!